# What are the commands at gdb console?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, gdb

Xcode 4. So I can do p something to print a variable. What else I can do?

Comment: `h` is probably a good command to start with.

Comment: bt is something you're gonna use a lot. It displays the stack trace. All commands have long versions, by the way.

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/

Comment: I voted to close for ["General Reference"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86043/introduce-a-general-reference-close-reason), using "Not a Real Question" as proxy.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Because you obviously don't want anything complete but only some pointers, you can

- `list`: list the lines around current position
- `list -`: list lines before that
- just enter: do the same thing again
- `cont`: continue
- `break 'Class::method()'`: set a breakpoint
- `run`: run the program from the start
- `start`: run and stop in main()
- `kill`: kill the running program
- `fin`: continue until the function returns
- `up`/`down`: go up/down one stack frame
- `bt`: get the backtrace
- `t a a bt` (thread apply all bt): get a backtrace for all threads
- `step`: run until different code line (descending into functions)
- `next`: run until different code line (skipping over functions)
- `commands`: set automatic actions on breakpoints
- `en`/`dis`/`del`: enable/disable/delete breakpoints
- `catch throw`: enable breaking when an exception is thrown
- `return <value>`: force the function to return *now* and return `<value>`
- `set pagination off`: disable --- More --- prompt
- `set history save on`
- `set history filename /home/<user>/.gdb_history`
  (both of those at best in `/home/<user>/.gdbinit`)
- ... and ... `help`: get help about any gdb command

So far my random collection.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you should take a look at this (very) quick GDB tutorial I wrote (I'm also using XCode).
Then refer to the official documentation. There are also plenty of online tutorials. Google is your friend.

http://www.eosgarden.com/en/articles/gdb-tutorial/